# Shared library installed at /usr/local/lib/ during package creation while sitepackages during package installation

Tags: python, linux, cmake, setuptools

#### Phase 1: Python wheel creation

While building a python package [wheel] using

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The wheel contains python files and package along with shared libraries `*.so`

After compilation of the shared libraries they get installed at the target location `/usr/local/lib/` which is the default value for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Refer [official doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)

```
/usr/local/lib/<name>.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/local/lib/libabc.so
```

alongside the site-packages folder

#### Phase 2: Python wheel installation

However, in a user's machine, when he/she attempts to install the wheel using

```
pip install <name>.whl
```

The shared libraries are only installed under the site-packages directory

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<name>.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libabc.so
```

#### Question

How can we ensure that the shared libraries get installed in the `/usr/local/lib` folder?

We need it in `/usr/local/lib` because the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/.openmpi/lib/:/opt/conda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

It would be undesirable for the user to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

So the ideal solution would be to ensure that `pip install` results in storing of shared libraries (`.so`) in a directory which is already supported by the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: your requirement contradicts the installation isolation. suppose that tomorrow you will want to install another version (side by side).

Comment: I dont think our users would need to have 2 versions of same python package at the same time. Also what is meant by "requirement contracts installation isolation"? what is the ideal solution for this problem?

Comment: What shared libraries do you mean exactly? If you are building C extension modules, those are meant to be loaded by Python interpreter only and should be put under site-packages, just as any regular Python module. If you are building shared libs via CMake which your C extension modules link against, those are put under `sys.prefix`/`lib` and your C extension modules should link against those local copies exclusively, as Python can't guarantee what shared libs are provided by the target platform.

Comment: Yes C extension modules. Thanks for confirming that they should be under site-packages. Should they be inside the package folder or just in the site-packages? does it matter?